# can't figure out Makefile with complicated dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a task at hand where my source file is under:

```
apps/$(APP_NAME)/$(APP_ENV)/$(APP_NAME).yml
```

then I need to process those files into:

```
.output/$(APP_NAME)/$(APP_ENV).yml
```

I am failing to sort out the rules for such Makefile where my APP_NAME is dynamic and comes from

```
APP_NAMES=$(shell ls -1 $(APP_DIRS))
```

I am able to do singular dependencies no problem:

```
OUTPUT_DIR:=.output
APPS_DIR:=apps
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/app1/prod.yml: $(APPS_DIR)/app1/prod/app1.yml
    $(eval APP_ENV=$(patsubst %.yml, %, $(patsubst $(OUTPUT_DIR)/%, %, $@)))
    $(eval APP=$(dir $(APP_ENV)))
    $(eval ENV=$(notdir $(APP_ENV)))
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    my_process --app=$(APP) --environment=$(ENV) --apps-dir=$(APPS_DIR) > $@
```

however making an implicit dynamic rule escapes me.

Comment: Pattern rules can handle only one wildcard at a time. What you want can be done, but it's tricky. You say `APP_NAME` comes from a call to `ls`; where does `APP_ENV` come from?

Comment: APP_ENV combo is basically an extraction of that pair from target's path in form APP_NAME/ENV which is further decomposed by the code (dir/notdir part)

Comment: You can't do this with pattern rule, because of a "single wildcard" limitation. Use $(foreach...) to generate a bunch of explicit rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern rules can only have one occurence of `%` but your case would require two.

I would try generating the necessary rules on the fly with a macro and then `$(eval)` them. If I understand your requirements correctly then this makefile should do it:

```makefile
# first rule in makefile is the default
.PHONY: all
all:

OUTPUT_DIR  := .output
APPS_DIR    := apps

# set as a fixed list for the solution - can be dynamic
SOURCE_YMLS := \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test1/prod/test1.yml \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test1/env1/test1.yml \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test1/env2/test1.yml \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test2/stage/test2.yml \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test2/env3/test2.yml \
    $(APPS_DIR)/test2/env4/test2.yml \

OUTPUT_YMLS :=
OUTPUT_DIRS :=

# $(1): source file name $(APPS_DIR)/<app_name>/<app_env>/<app_name>.yml
define generate_yml_rule
_input_parts := $(subst /, ,$(patsubst $(APPS_DIR)/%,%,$(1)))
_app_name    := $$(word 1,$$(_input_parts))
_app_env     := $$(word 2,$$(_input_parts))
_output_dir  := $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$$(_app_name)
_output_yml  := $$(_output_dir)/$$(_app_env).yml

# target specific variables for recipe evaluation
$$(_output_yml): _app_name := $$(_app_name)
$$(_output_yml): _app_env  := $$(_app_env)

# why does "myprocess" not use $$< directly ???
# NOTE: >$$@ commented out for testing only
$$(_output_yml): $(1) | $$(_output_dir)
    @echo my_process --app=$$(_app_name) --environment=$$(_app_env) --apps-dir=$(APPS_DIR) # >$$@

OUTPUT_DIRS += $$(_output_dir)
OUTPUT_YMLS += $$(_output_yml)

_input_parts :=
_app_name    :=
_app_env     :=
_output_dir  :=
_output_yml  :=

endef

# generate rules for output yml files
$(eval \
    $(foreach _f,$(SOURCE_YMLS), \
        $(call generate_yml_rule,$(_f)) \
    ) \
)

# remove duplicate directories
OUTPUT_DIRS := $(sort $(OUTPUT_DIRS))

$(info OUTPUT_DIRS '$(OUTPUT_DIRS)')
$(info OUTPUT_YMLS '$(OUTPUT_YMLS)')

all: $(OUTPUT_YMLS)
    @echo DONE

$(OUTPUT_DIRS): | $(OUTPUT_DIR)
$(OUTPUT_DIRS) $(OUTPUT_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

If we prepend `info` in front of `eval` then we make the generated code visible (excerpt only):

```makefile
eval  _input_parts := test1 prod test1.yml
_app_name    := $(word 1,$(_input_parts))
_app_env     := $(word 2,$(_input_parts))
_output_dir  := .output/$(_app_name)
_output_yml  := $(_output_dir)/$(_app_env).yml

# target specific variables for recipe evaluation
$(_output_yml): _app_name := $(_app_name)
$(_output_yml): _app_env  := $(_app_env)

# why does "myprocess" not use $< directly ???
# NOTE: >$@ commented out for testing only
$(_output_yml): apps/test1/prod/test1.yml | $(_output_dir)
        @echo my_process --app=$(_app_name) --environment=$(_app_env) --apps-dir=apps # >$@

OUTPUT_DIRS += $(_output_dir)
OUTPUT_YMLS += $(_output_yml)

_input_parts :=
_app_name    :=
_app_env     :=
_output_dir  :=
_output_yml  :=
   _input_parts := test1 env1 test1.yml
_app_name    := $(word 1,$(_input_parts))
_app_env     := $(word 2,$(_input_parts))
_output_dir  := .output/$(_app_name)
_output_yml  := $(_output_dir)/$(_app_env).yml

# target specific variables for recipe evaluation
$(_output_yml): _app_name := $(_app_name)
$(_output_yml): _app_env  := $(_app_env)

# why does "myprocess" not use $< directly ???
# NOTE: >$@ commented out for testing only
$(_output_yml): apps/test1/env1/test1.yml | $(_output_dir)
        @echo my_process --app=$(_app_name) --environment=$(_app_env) --apps-dir=apps # >$@

OUTPUT_DIRS += $(_output_dir)
OUTPUT_YMLS += $(_output_yml)

_input_parts :=
... and so on for the 4 other source files...
```

Test run (`myprocess` commented out with `echo` to show what is happening):

```
$ make
OUTPUT_DIRS '.output/test1 .output/test2'
OUTPUT_YMLS ' .output/test1/prod.yml .output/test1/env1.yml .output/test1/env2.yml .output/test2/stage.yml .output/test2/env3.yml .output/test2/env4.yml'
mkdir -p .output
mkdir -p .output/test1
my_process --app=test1 --environment=prod --apps-dir=apps
my_process --app=test1 --environment=env1 --apps-dir=apps
my_process --app=test1 --environment=env2 --apps-dir=apps
mkdir -p .output/test2
my_process --app=test2 --environment=stage --apps-dir=apps
my_process --app=test2 --environment=env3 --apps-dir=apps
my_process --app=test2 --environment=env4 --apps-dir=apps
DONE
```

Comment: I need to iterate over *all* APP_NAME and corresponding APP_ENV combinations. For example app1 can have (prod,env1,env2) and app2 can have (stage,env3,env4) environments. How would you reflect that in above code (I'm still dissecting your response thus may be missing the obvious)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer

Comment: thanks! I'll validate this tomorrow and see how that fits my environment! :)

Comment: couldn't resist - plugged above code (with minor modifications to align with my environment) and it worked as expected. this is great!