# Is there a way for having multiple wildcards?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I try to use *GNU make* to organize my research data, processing and visualization as recommended by the [Data Science CookieCutter project](http://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science). My raw data is structured like this:

```
.
├── data
│   ├── interim
│   │   └── cleaned
│   └── raw
│       ├── ex01
│       └── ex02
```

Where I keep the data of experiment 1 and 2 seperated but combine them after cleaning them. Eg `data/raw/ex01/p0-c0.csv` becomes `data/interim/cleaned/ex01-p0-c0.hdf`.

In *make* I use two rules like this:

```
data/interim/cleaned/ex01-%.hdf: data/raw/ex01/source0/%.csv 
data/raw/ex01/source1/%.csv
  $(PYTHON) src/data/make_dataset.py $^ $@

data_interim_cleaned_ex01: $(addprefix $(CLEANED_DIR)/ex01-, $(addsuffix .hdf, $(basename $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard data/raw/ex01/source0/*.csv))))))
```

This strikes me as oddly verbose (especially because I copied the block for experiment 2) and I my intuition tells me that it would be easier if there were multiple (named) wildcards. I guess regexps would help, but are not (easily) available in *make*.

Is there a canonical way to solve this?

Comment: Use variables and internal functions (foreach, patsubst, etc.) to decrease verbosity and to avoid repetitions. But there's no way to make use of regexps and/or multiple wildcards in GNU make's rules.

Comment: Just to be clear, the terminology here is _patterns_ not wildcards.  There is a `$(wildcard ...)` function that support full globbing but it's different than patterns, which are used to create pattern rules.  As mentioned, there can only be one pattern character (`%`) in a pattern.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504851/cant-figure-out-makefile-with-complicated-dependencies/55509012?noredirect=1#comment97744554_55509012) I posted today for a similar question. In short: use a macro to generate the rule contents and `$(eval)` those.

Comment: To further clarify, the `%` is referred to as the _stem_, whereas `%.c` would be the _pattern_.   `%.c: %.o ... ` would be a _pattern rule_.   There can only be one stem per pattern rule.

Comment: Doing a loop using `foreach` and `eval` would do what you want, but beware evals often make the makefile hard to understand/maintain by a common user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't figure out Makefile with complicated dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504851/cant-figure-out-makefile-with-complicated-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution isn't really a canonical `make` file but IMHO much of the canonical functionality of make is too hard to grasp and remember anyway. Questions like "how can I transform my set of filenames from shape X to Y" come up all the time because users *do* employ directory and filename structure as means to organize their projects (a very natural and logical way) and `make` is really badly equipped to handle such tasks programmatically.

One way is to use the usual range of command line tools like `sed`, the other are helper libraries like [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) to take apart strings:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

COMMON_ROOT = data/raw
COMMON_DEST = data/interim/cleaned

SOURCE = data/raw/ex01/p0-c0.csv data/raw/ex01/p1-c1.csv data/raw/ex02/p0-c0.csv data/raw/ex02/p1-c1.csv

# a pattern which separates a string into 5 parts (see below)
SEP_PATTERN = $(COMMON_ROOT)/ex*/*.csv

# use the elements (quoted variable-references '$$'!) in the new filename 
OUTPUT_PATTERN = $(COMMON_DEST)/ex$$2-$$4.hdf

# glob-match tests a glob pattern on a string and returns the string cut up at the border of 
# the glob elements (*,?,[] and verbatim strings). We immediately turn this into a gmtt table 
# by prepending the number of columns (5) to it:
SEPARATED = 5 $(foreach fname,$(SOURCE),$(call glob-match,$(fname),$(SEP_PATTERN)))

$(info $(SEPARATED))
$(info -----------------) 
$(info $(call map-tbl,$(SEPARATED),$(OUTPUT_PATTERN)$$(newline)))
```

Output:

```
$ make
5 data/raw/ex 01 / p0-c0 .csv data/raw/ex 01 / p1-c1 .csv data/raw/ex 02 / p0-c0 .csv data/raw/ex 02 / p1-c1 .csv
-----------------
data/interim/cleaned/ex01-p0-c0.hdf
data/interim/cleaned/ex01-p1-c1.hdf
data/interim/cleaned/ex02-p0-c0.hdf
data/interim/cleaned/ex02-p1-c1.hdf

make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.
```

I fear that turning the makefile into one which generates rules dynamically is inevitable, tho.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is perhaps not one you are going to like, but it is to not introduce variability or repetition in you file names. There are easy or at least reasonable ways to articulate relationships in a `Makefile` between stem names where you add or remove a prefix (such as a directory name) or a suffix. Anything else creates complications where you end up with tortured and complex transformation rules or external helper scripts to manage the mappings, or, in the worst care, a situation where you simply have to abandon `make` for dependency management.

One workaround which sort of allows you to keep your cake and eat it too is to set up symlinks between your preferred, human-friendly naming conventions and the structures managed by `make`; but this is a crutch at best.

Another technique which may be useful to you is to `touch` a simple flag file to mark a complex set of dependencies as handled. Especially if there are dependencies which do not map directly to a set of input file names for another target, putting all of those behind a simple

```
.input-files-done: some complex depencies
    touch $@
```

and then just depending on `.input-files-done` for the targets which share these dependencies can simplify your `Makefile` and your workflow.

But in summary, my main recommendation would be to keep file names uniform, so that you can always declare an explicit dependency from one file name to another with a simple rule.